# How can I draw freehand circles on screenshots?

Tags: preview, drawing

In Windows I can happily fire up MS Paint and draw [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/152279) with the brush tool on top of my screenshots.

In OS X if I open up a screenshot with Preview and use the pen-looking thing and draw a freehand circle, it's automatically converted into a soulless oval. I also can't draw squiggly arrows or poorly scrawled text.

Short of launching Photoshop (or whatever non-default app), is there a baked-in way to draw freehand circles in OS X?

Comment: Additionally, in the new OS X you get a screenshot thumbnail, which brings up additional editing tools when clicked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

But you can draw freehand circles in **Preview**, just select the shape you want to use in the upper left corner after you draw the shape. If you don't see the controls as below, go to **View → Show Markup Toolbar**

[image: Preview with shape selection]

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that popping up for some reason.

Comment: For those wondering where these controls are: `View> Show Markup Toolbar`